# Slow scrolling of a widget on the page relative to other widgets

Tags: flutter, dart

**Check out the gif below:**

[image: gif]

- If you pay attention to the images on the page while **scrolling**, you will notice that one of the images is different from the other while scrolling the page.
  It moves slower and **scrolls** **slowly**!
- How can such a thing be implemented?

Comment: ask Google for "flutter parallax effect" the first answer is https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/effects/parallax-scrolling